# Newly opened apps have blurry icon background in dock (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, dock

When I open an app that ISN'T added to the dock (not in favorites), then the app icon background becomes blurry. This effect disappears when I hover over the app with my mouse, or select another window, but reappears again if I remove the cursor from the app icon, or if I select the app again through the dock.

In this picture the terminal has a blurry background:

[image: Picture - the terminal has a blurry background]

Anyone else who has this problem? Found a fix? I don't have any gnome extensions, just freshly installed 22.04.

EDIT: I've also noticed this only happens with some apps, like terminal that's opened with CTRL+ALT+T, or settings

EDIT 2: `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2507 (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 887c
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: I would assume it's either a design decision or a bug in gnome-shell. If it's a bug, it might go away with a future update. If it's a design feature, it may get updated with time too, given enough feedback draws the attention of the maintainer to it. A third option could be a glitch involving your specific graphics stack. In this case, - even though I have no idea what I'm talking about, I still think that - updating the post with the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` could be beneficial...

Comment: Also, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, so it might be different, but I for one could try changing the settings for this UI element. In 20.04 this piece of UI is a gnome shell extension (called "Dash to Dock") that ships with Ubuntu and is enabled by default, so it has a settings interface. One can `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, which offers a GUI for a range of advanced settings. It has a search function, wherein one can put `dash-to-dock`, and on 20.04, it reveals dozens of settings that impact the appearance of this thing. If you are lucky, there may be a setting to change the feature in question.

Comment: Someone else posted a similar observation, and they also have an nvidia stack: https://askubuntu.com/q/1446336/1157519

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Ubuntu Dock but I was able to fix it by following these steps:

1.Download the Gnome Extension application.

2.Navigate to Ubuntu Dock from Gnome extensions.

3.Disable Ubuntu Dock.

4.Enable Ubuntu Dock again.

This should fix the problem.