# Pixelated borders around icons on dock/panel

Tags: 22.04, icons, gnome-panel

Currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Sometimes icons will have a pixelated border around them when selected which is a minor issue but still slightly annoying.

Examples:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Sometimes they look normal again after restarting the application or right clicking on the icon, so I'm really not sure what is causing the problem.

Edit:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] driver: nvidia v: 525.60.11
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia resolution: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.60.11
```

Comment: Hi, open a terminal, and execute: `inxi -G`. Copy the output and add it **into your question** (not in the comments). I suspect your GPU...

Comment: This looks similar? https://askubuntu.com/q/1436887/1157519

Comment: Interesting, the other asker with this problem also has an nvidia stack.