# Blurry icon highlight behind dock/taskbar icons (22.04)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, wayland

This image is pretty self-explanatory. I know that this question was asked at least twice before, but no solution was proposed. Moreover I do not have an Nvidia GPU, but an Intel integrated GPU instead. My Ubuntu installation is brand new too. I only have changed Ubuntu settings.

[image]

Here are the links to the other questions:

[Pixelated borders around icons on dock/panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446336/pixelated-borders-around-icons-on-dock-panel)
[Newly opened apps have blurry icon background in dock (Ubuntu 22.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436887/newly-opened-apps-have-blurry-icon-background-in-dock-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes it but I have Intel graphics and I just noticed this bug too. For me what seems to (temporarily) fix it is to restart Gnome (alt+F2 -> type "r" then press enter)

Comment: When I created this question I mistakenly wrote that I was using Ubuntu 20.04 instead of Ubuntu 22.04. ‍♂️
I am also using Wayland, which does not have the restart command you mentioned. Thank you anyways for your answer, I appreciate it.